# How to save a file using for loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I'm having a excel data contain like below:

| x | y0 | y1 | y2 | y3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.101 | 0.189 | 0.158 | 0.258 |
| 0 | 0.112 | 0.215 | 0.258 | 0.358 |
| 0 | 0.241 | 0.289 | 0.315 | 0.415 |

I have loaded this data in the jupyter notebook and assigning 'df'.

I wanted to extract the x and y1 columns and save as .txt file. Similarly, I wanted to get each .txt file containing x, y2 and x, y4. I wanted to use for loop to save.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
for i in range(4):
    s = db[['x', y[i]]
    s.to_csv('y[i].txt', index=False) #I dunno how to save each file.
```

How to get the .txt file as y1.txt, y2.txt?
This query may looks so simple for the people here, but the answer from you is so helpful for me.

Comment: f-string with `f'y{i}.txt'`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is:
f-string's, If you don't know about it, google it.

Solution:

```py
for i in range(4):
    s = X[['x', f'y{i}']]
    s.to_csv(f'y{i}.txt', index=False)
```